# How to perform super pixel image segmentation and feature extraction

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-segmentation, multilabel-classification, superpixels

I am interested in multi class segmentation of skin tissues, I have 3000 skin tissue labels classified into 4 classes,  I have created a CNN classification algorithm to train my classification model. I would like to use the classification model for segmentation task of new skin tissue image and perform feature extraction of the skin tissue belonging to each of the class

Following is the code that is written to train my classification model

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Concatenate, Dropout, Flatten, Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
#from tensorflow.keras.utils import np_utils
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import top_k_categorical_accuracy
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model, load_model
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.initializers import he_uniform
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, LearningRateScheduler, TensorBoard, EarlyStopping, CSVLogger, ReduceLROnPlateau
#from tensorflow.compat.keras.backend import KTF
#import keras.backend.tensorflow_backend as KTF
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3

import os
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
#import numpy as np, Pillow, skimage, imageio, matplotlib
#from scipy.misc import imresize
from skimage.transform import resize
from tqdm import tqdm
from tensorflow.keras import metrics

#### PREPROCESS STAGE ####

# Path to superpixels class files
classes_file = "/home/DEV/SKIN_3000_CLASSES.csv"
concatenated_data= pd.read_csv(classes_file, header=None)

# Instances with targets
targets = concatenated_data[1].tolist()

# Split data according to their classes
class_0 = concatenated_data[concatenated_data[1] == 0]
class_1 = concatenated_data[concatenated_data[1] == 1]
class_2 = concatenated_data[concatenated_data[1] == 2]
class_3 = concatenated_data[concatenated_data[1] == 3]

# Holdout split train/test set (Other options are k-folds or leave-one-out)
split_proportion = 0.8

split_size_0 = int(len(class_0)*split_proportion)
split_size_1 = int(len(class_1)*split_proportion)
split_size_2 = int(len(class_2)*split_proportion)
split_size_3 = int(len(class_3)*split_proportion)

new_class_0_train = np.random.choice(len(class_0), split_size_0, replace=False)
new_class_0_train = class_0.iloc[new_class_0_train]
new_class_0_test = ~class_0.iloc[:][0].isin(new_class_0_train.iloc[:][0])
new_class_0_test = class_0[new_class_0_test]

new_class_1_train = np.random.choice(len(class_1), split_size_1, replace=False)
new_class_1_train = class_1.iloc[new_class_1_train]
new_class_1_test = ~class_1.iloc[:][0].isin(new_class_1_train.iloc[:][0])
new_class_1_test = class_1[new_class_1_test]

new_class_2_train = np.random.choice(len(class_2), split_size_2, replace=False)
new_class_2_train = class_2.iloc[new_class_2_train]
new_class_2_test = ~class_2.iloc[:][0].isin(new_class_2_train.iloc[:][0])
new_class_2_test = class_2[new_class_2_test]

new_class_3_train = np.random.choice(len(class_3), split_size_3, replace=False)
new_class_3_train = class_3.iloc[new_class_3_train]
new_class_3_test = ~class_3.iloc[:][0].isin(new_class_3_train.iloc[:][0])
new_class_3_test = class_3[new_class_3_test]

x_train_list = pd.concat(
    [new_class_0_train, new_class_1_train, new_class_2_train, new_class_3_train])
x_test_list = pd.concat(
    [new_class_0_test, new_class_1_test, new_class_2_test, new_class_3_test])

# Load superpixels files
imagePath = "/home/DEV/SKIN_SET_3000/"

x_train = []
y_train = []
for index, row in tqdm(x_train_list.iterrows(), total=x_train_list.shape[0]):
    try:
        loadedImage = plt.imread(imagePath + str(row[0]) + ".jpg")
        x_train.append(loadedImage)
        y_train.append(row[1])
    except:
        # Try with .png file format if images are not properly loaded
        try:
            loadedImage = plt.imread(imagePath + str(row[0]) + ".png")
            x_train.append(loadedImage)
            y_train.append(row[1])
        except:
            # Print file names whenever it is impossible to load image files
            print(imagePath + str(row[0]))

x_test = []
y_test = []
for index, row in tqdm(x_test_list.iterrows(), total=x_test_list.shape[0]):
    try:
        loadedImage = plt.imread(imagePath + str(row[0]) + ".jpg")
        x_test.append(loadedImage)
        y_test.append(row[1])
    except:
        # Try with .png file format if images are not properly loaded
        try:
            loadedImage = plt.imread(imagePath + str(row[0]) + ".png")
            x_test.append(loadedImage)
            y_test.append(row[1])
        except:
            # Print file names whenever it is impossible to load image files
            print(imagePath + str(row[0]))


# Reescaling of images 
img_width, img_height = 139, 139

index = 0
for image in tqdm(x_train):
    #aux = resize(image, (img_width, img_height, 3), "bilinear")
    aux = resize(image, (img_width, img_height))
    x_train[index] = aux / 255.0  # Normalization
    index += 1

index = 0
for image in tqdm(x_test):
    #aux = resize(image, (img_width, img_height, 3), "bilinear")
    aux = resize(image, (img_width, img_height))
    x_test[index] = aux / 255.0  # Normalization
    index += 1




#### TRAINING STAGE ####

os.environ["KERAS_BACKEND"] = "tensorflow"
RANDOM_STATE = 42

def get_session(gpu_fraction=0.8):

    num_threads = os.environ.get('OMP_NUM_THREADS')
    gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=gpu_fraction)

    if num_threads:
        return tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(
            gpu_options=gpu_options, intra_op_parallelism_threads=num_threads))
    else:
        return tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options))


#KTF.set_session(get_session())


def precision(y_true, y_pred):

    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    predicted_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)))
    precision = true_positives / (predicted_positives + K.epsilon())
    return precision


def recall(y_true, y_pred):

    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    possible_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)))
    recall = true_positives / (possible_positives + K.epsilon())
    return recall


def fbeta_score(y_true, y_pred, beta=1):

    if beta < 0:
        raise ValueError('The lowest choosable beta is zero (only precision).')

    # Set F-score as 0 if there are no true positives (sklearn-like).
    if K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1))) == 0:
        return 0.0

    p = precision(y_true, y_pred)
    r = recall(y_true, y_pred)
    bb = beta ** 2
    fbeta_score = (1 + bb) * (p * r) / (bb * p + r + K.epsilon())
    return fbeta_score


nb_classes = 4
final_model = []


# Option = InceptionV3
model = InceptionV3(weights="imagenet", include_top=False,
                    input_shape=(img_width, img_height, 3))
# Option = ResNet
# model = ResNet50(weights="imagenet", include_top=False, input_shape=(3,img_width, img_height))

# Creating new outputs for the model
x = model.output
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(512, activation="relu")(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = Dense(512, activation="relu")(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
predictions = Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax')(x)
#predictions = Dense(nb_classes, activation='sigmoid')(x)
final_model = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=predictions)


# Metrics
learningRate = 0.001
optimizer = optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=learningRate, momentum=0.88, nesterov=True)

# Compiling the model...
final_model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=optimizer,
                    metrics=["accuracy", fbeta_score])
final_model.summary()

#final_model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])

#model.compile(loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])

#x_train = np.array(x_train)
#x_test = np.array(x_test)

x_train = np.asarray(x_train).astype(np.float32)
#x_test = np.array(x_test)
x_test = np.asarray(x_test).astype(np.float32)

# Defining targets...
y_train = np.concatenate([np.full((new_class_0_train.shape[0]), 0), np.full((new_class_1_train.shape[0]), 1),
                          np.full((new_class_2_train.shape[0]), 2), np.full((new_class_3_train.shape[0]), 3)])

y_test = np.concatenate([np.full((new_class_0_test.shape[0]), 0), np.full((new_class_1_test.shape[0]), 1),
                         np.full((new_class_2_test.shape[0]), 2), np.full((new_class_3_test.shape[0]), 3)])

y_train = to_categorical(y_train)
y_test =  to_categorical(y_test)

modelFilename = "/home/DEV/SKIN_SET_3000/model_inception.h5"

trainingFilename = "/home/DEV/SKIN_SET_3000/training.csv"
nb_train_samples = y_train.shape[0]
nb_test_samples = y_test.shape[0]
#epochs = 10000
epochs = 100
batch_size = 24
trainingPatience = 200
decayPatience = trainingPatience / 4

# Setting the data generator...
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode="reflect",
    zoom_range=0.2
)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size)

# Saving the model
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(modelFilename,
                             monitor='val_accuracy',
                             verbose=1,
                             save_best_only=True,
                             save_weights_only=False,
                             mode='auto',
                             save_freq=1)

adaptativeLearningRate = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_accuracy',
                                           factor=0.5,
                                           patience=decayPatience,
                                           verbose=1,
                                           mode='auto',
                                           min_delta=0.0001,
                                           cooldown=0,
                                           min_lr=1e-8)

early = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy',
                      min_delta=0,
                      patience=trainingPatience,
                      verbose=1,
                      mode='auto')

csv_logger = CSVLogger(trainingFilename, separator=",", append=False)

# Callbacks
callbacks = [checkpoint, early, csv_logger, adaptativeLearningRate]

# Training of the model
final_model.fit(train_generator,
                          steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples / batch_size,
                          epochs=epochs,
                          shuffle=True,
                          validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
                          validation_steps=nb_test_samples / batch_size,
                          callbacks=callbacks)

final_model.save('/home/DEV/SKIN_SET_3000/model_inception.h5')
#compile metrics
```

In order to  segment my image, first i have transformed my input image to super pixel  using SLIC

```
from skimage.segmentation import slic
from skimage.segmentation import mark_boundaries
from skimage.util import img_as_float
from skimage import io; io.use_plugin('matplotlib')
import cv2 as cv
from skimage.color import label2rgb

img_width, img_height = 139, 139

# load the model we saved
model = load_model('/home/DEV/SKIN_SET_3000/model_inception.h5', compile=False)

# Get test image ready
 img = skimage.img_as_float(skimage.io.imread('/home/DEV/SKIN_ULCER.jpg')).astype(np.float32)
plt.imshow(img)
test_image_slic = slic(img, n_segments=500, compactness=10.0)
test_image_slic_out = mark_boundaries(img,test_image_slic)
plt.imshow(test_image_slic_out)
#test_image=test_image/255
test_image_array = np.array(test_image_slic_out)
test_image_resize = cv2.resize(test_image_array,(img_width,img_height))
test_image_reshape = test_image_resize.reshape(1,img_width, img_height,3)
```

I would like to check if each superpixel of my input is labeled as one of my target class among 4 tissue classes, and extract the features belonging to each class as a mask and quantify the total surface area of mask .
any suggestions of how to implement this approach would be appreciated.

Comment: May be this link is helpful: https://github.com/topics/superpixels